# Im trying to log something when a person uses the say command. The bot is in multiple servers.How do i get it to log in a channel for multiple servers

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have a say command written. I want it to log for example, {ctx.author.name} said {message}. But my bot is in multiple servers so how would i write the code to tell the bot, (in this guild, log to "this channel id") basically? This is the code that i have already.

```
async def say(ctx, *, text):
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"{text}")
```

Comment: Make a per guild configuration and use `get_channel` based on that guilds id. Think dictionary where `guild.id` is the key and `channel.id` is the value

Comment: I think you shold check what you get in `ctx`. Probably you should have informat on what channel it was executed.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# "bot" is your variable to interract with your discord bot account. Replace with your variable name
bot = discord.Client()

...

# Your log channel's ID
SAY_LOG_CHANNEL_ID = 88989889898989

async def say(ctx, *, text):
    message = ctx.message
    await message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"{text}")

    # Log into your channel
    log_channel = bot.get_channel(SAY_LOG_CHANNEL_ID)
    if log_channel:
        await log.channel.send(f"{message.author.name} | {message.guild.name} | (={message.channel.name} (ID: {message.channel.id}) said {message}")
```

Comment: you send all to one channel - but OP wants to send different guilds to different channels

Comment: Yes, furas is correct. the bot is in different guilds so what would the code be for that? Thx!

Comment: Then, just put channel's ID instead of SAY_LOG_CHANNEL_ID for each guild